# Long running we request, UI gets timed out by the time response is ready

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, angular-fullstack

I have one angular app and one spring boot app, there is one request goes from UI to spring boot with some 100-200 objects even more, for each of these objects another back end system is called within a loop.
something like..

```
list.parallelStream().forEach(e->{

    //code using rest template for backend.
    // add the responses to an array list.
    // i can send all these objects to backend at one shot because they have some limitations and dont support it currently. 
});
```

This takes a lot of time to complete and by the time all the request is completed the UI gets timed out.

I tried using executer framework, forkjoin or parallel but this is not enough. because browser wait for 30-60 sec.

I want to switch to anyc process where i submit request to spring boot, from UI I should be able to check the status of the request after time interval. i tried concepts like DeferredResult, @Async, completeable future and StreamingResponseBody. is there any way to handle these long running request???

Some of these concepts works but when the input size increase they also fail to work properly. how do i manage to get the status of my request and use some progress bar etc to show even user.
or any better approch?

Answer (score 0):

For me it sounds like you want to stream data.

Perhaps spring's reactive stack is something you want to look at:

- [Building a Reactive RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/)
- [Video Tutorial using Kotlin](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQ176FUIyIUbyly9kfmbxFk1U6dV-Y_kY)

With this your angular app should be able to display or react very finished processing of an individual item as they happen.

Hope that helps.